# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, system.web.optimization

I am having an issue with my Asp.net MVC 5 project in visual studio 2013. 
My DLL for System.Web.Optimization is version 1.1.40211.0
but under the references for the project it says the version is 1.1.0.0

I am not sure how to go about checking what code is looking for the version that I do not have.

Thanks for the help!

Error Below

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Optimization' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Optimization
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: System.Web.Optimization | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/mike.schmidt/Google Drive/U4/WebApplicationMVCIdentity2/WebApplicationMVCIdentity2/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\mike.schmidt\Google Drive\U4\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\mike.schmidt\Google Drive\U4\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\mike.schmidt\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/14e1ae6d/1481a15f/System.Web.Optimization.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/14e1ae6d/1481a15f/System.Web.Optimization/System.Web.Optimization.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/mike.schmidt/Google Drive/U4/WebApplicationMVCIdentity2/WebApplicationMVCIdentity2/bin/System.Web.Optimization.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\mike.schmidt\Google Drive\U4\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\WebApplicationMVCIdentity2\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\mike.schmidt\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80070057). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9950728
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

Comment: Has this ever worked before?

Comment: Yes it was working before. I do not recall updating any of the packages. and when I use AWS Console to push it to a website it works. but when i debug it locally it doesn't. I've tried deleting all my compiled files and building it clean, but that doesn't work. I know I'm probably missing something, but i can't figure out what

Comment: What if you clean THEN, remove all of the references and replace them again?

Comment: What References are you referring to? I have tried to remove the reference for System.Web.Optimization

Comment: Do a `Clean Solution` and `Rebuild Solution` by right clicking on the project solution folder and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, reinstalling of [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.1.3) in Package Manager Console should solve the problem.

```
Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
```

If still doesn't solve the problem, remove all packages (and references), delete all DLLs and install packages should work.

Comment: PM> Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Update-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'.
At line:1 char:15
+ Update-Package <<<<  –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], InvalidOpera 
   tionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.UpdatePackageCommand

Comment: I am running 'Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'

Comment: Now i Get this error Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Look like you need to install *(if you have never installed)* or re-install Antlr3.Runtime too.

Comment: As it turns out the 1.1.3 nuget package actually contains a DLL versioned 1.1.0, which you can verify by opening the DLL in ILSpy